# How can I tell whether speakers are magnetically shielded?

Tags: speakers

I have recently "inherited" a 2003 Philips sound system with fairly decent compact speakers.

The specifications in [the manual](http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/m/mz-1000_37/mz-1000_37_dfu_aen.pdf) do not appear to state whether the speakers are magnetically shielded. Is there any simple way to find out?

Comment: Could it be as simple as holding a compass close to them?

Comment: Good idea! @mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them next to a CRT TV or computer screen. It's not a very high tech way to find out, but it's sure to change the image if they are not. Don't leave them there for long as they could damage your screen. You could also open them up and check visually. If you see bare magnet, they are not shielded. Then again, they could just be painted over.

Either method is not sure. Also the sheilding may not very good but provide *some* degree of shielding. So even thought the manufacturer may state they are shielded, they might not be shielded very well at all.

If you are really concerned and you don't trust the manuafacturer, you may want to use a gauss meter. I found this page:
http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magmeter.htm

Comment: Thanks. Placing them too close to the only CRT screen I own is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, since it doesn't have a degauss function. :-)

Comment: That sounds like a very old screen. LCDs are quite affordable these days. In any case, shielded speakers are a good idea.